# How to send mail using my domain name and SMTP server

Tags: php, smtp, localhost, domain-name, sendmail.exe

My requirement is to send a mail to the client's mail-id. I wrote a program in php to send mail using SMTP server and hosted it on localhost. It worked fine and I was able to send the mail successfully. I used port 25.

Now I want to run the same program using the same sender id, this time by hosting the php program on my domain name. But, I'm not able to send the mail. What changes should I make?
Please note, I don't want to send mails using my domain email. I want  to send mails using the same gmail id which i used for localhost.

My sendmail.ini looks like this:

```
; configuration for fake sendmail

; if this file doesn't exist, sendmail.exe will look for the settings in
; the registry, under HKLM\Software\Sendmail

[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=25

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=auto

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

default_domain=my_domain_name.com

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=my_sender_id@gmail.com    
auth_password=my_password

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=my_sender_id@gmail.com

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content

force_recipient=

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=
```

Comment: Could you specify what the problem is? Errors? Logs?

Comment: @Bowdzone I want to host a php program on my domain space that sends e-mail to a Gmail id using SMTP

Comment: Again. You only said "But, I'm not able to send the mail". Please include specific information what happens when you try to execute your script. Error messages, log files and such

Comment: @Bowdzone Nothing is updated in error.log/debug.log files and no error messages are shown when I host the program on my domain name. But when I run the same code using localhost, error/debug files are updated and mail is sent.